# How to enable Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I wonder why my Spring security is not working. I've got this spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

     <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <port-mappings>
            <port-mapping http="8088" https="9443"/>
        </port-mappings>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="password2" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Then I got this web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/admin-servlet-common.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/admin-servlet-controller.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/admin-servlet-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/admin-servlet-service.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            classpath:ses-service.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Reads request input using UTF-8 encoding -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Enables clean URLs with JSP views e.g. /welcome instead of /app/welcome -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ses</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ses</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But it neither gives an error message nor enables security. There is no change is my webapp and I can still browse the pages e.g. `http://localhost:8088/admin/login` and `http://localhost:8088/admin/menu` . This project is the admin part of a web app and I'm enabling security for the admin web. What can be done? My own login page that I'd like to use is `http://localhost:8088/admin/login` and I'd like to secure the rest of the /admin* pages for the admin role.

Comment: put a breakpoint in your application and check the stack, is the spring security filter even called?

Comment: I'm guessing your spring security file is named `admin-servlet-security.xml` ?  Cause if not you need to add it to the `contextConfigLocation` list in your web.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UrlRewriteFilter is listed first and will bypass Spring Security by forwarding to other places within the application. In general, the springSecurityFilterChain should be the first  in your web.xml to ensure it intercepts all requests.

I'd also consider removing UrlRewriteFilter all together (as it can make for very confusing mappings in your intercept-urls. In the past it was used to remove the /app mapping assigned to Springs DispatcherServlet which can easily be avoided by mapping the DispatcherServlet to /

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ses</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You can find some more discussion about Spring Security and UrlRewriteFilter on the [Spring Security forums](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/93146-struggling-with-urlrewrite-and-spring-security-need-directions)

Answer (score 1):

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

does it means that you allow access to all pages for user with ROLE_USER (all of 3 users have that role)?

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

should allow access to admin's pages only for users with ROLE_ADMIN, and rest of pages as it works now